# Difficulty building a one-to-one relationship in Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entity with names product and productDetails
And there is a one-to-one relationship between them.

But when I open my mysql it shows me that they have a one to many relationship?

Why is there such a problem?

*ProductDetails class*

```
    @Getter
    
    @Setter
    
    @Entity
    public class ProductDetail {
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "product_id")
        private Integer id;
        private String description;
        private float weight;
        private float length;
        private float height;
        private float width;
    
        @OneToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
        @MapsId
        private product product;
    }
```

*Product class*

```
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Entity
    public class product {
    
        @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;
    
        private String name;
        private float price;
    
        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
        private ProductDetail detail;
    
        public product() { }
    
        public product(String name, float price) {
            super();
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
        }
```

> Reverse Enginer in mysql

[image]

Comment: All foreign keys are 1:M mappings from the other side. The tool is likely looking at the FK only, treating your primary key constraint (and its uniqueness requirement) separate from the mapping multiplicity calculation. PS you can't have both MapsId AND mark that same ID as a generated value in the ProductDetail class. It needs to be set from either the relationship, or the database assign it a value, but you can't mark it as set using both. And also remove the @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn from Product's detail - it only confuses things.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is maybe MySQL reverse engineering.

but try removing `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` from the Product Details class.When you use product PK as shared primary key you don't need to generate an id in Product Details again.